# spring data jpa @EntityGraph method with Collection result throws BeanCreationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.server.repository.location.CityDao.findAllWithCountry()! No property findAllWithCountry found for type City!

```
@Transactional
public interface CityDao extends JpaRepository<City, Integer> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "country")
    List<City> findAllWithCountry(); //this one does not work

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "country")
    City findOneWithCountryById(int id); //this one works
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"country", "city_name", "latitude", "longitude"})
})
@Data
public class City {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "country")
    private Country country;
}
```

I'm trying to implement `@EntityGraph` to improve API performance. 
The first method throws `BeanCreationException` while the second one is working. The only difference is the first one returns a collection and the second one returns a single entity. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is not the `country` attribute for `City`, take a look at the stacktrace:

```
No property findAllWithCountry found for type City!
```

That means it can't derive the query *at all*, let alone find the `country` attribute.

You can either override the default `findAll`:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "country")
@Override
List<City> findAll();
```

Which will apply this optimization to all of your `findAll`.

When I have encountered this in the past (where I want to have multiple derived methods with the same query properties, but different annotations per), is to write the [customize the base repo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository) or write the query with `@Query`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data `find…By` keyword lets you fill in the dotted space on your choice ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject)).

So you can write something like

```
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "country")
    List<City> findAllWithCountryBy();

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "city")
    List<City> findAllWithCityBy();

    // ...
```